# Socket thread blocks main thread when receiving

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am using a socket thread.
It takes about 5 to 10 seconds to receive a message after sending a request message.
during that time I want my main thread to show "Please wait" popup.
The process flow of the program looks something like this.

1. show Popup
2. create socket thread.
   -> this will connect to server
3. send request message to server
4. receive message.

My problem is that the show popup does not show up,
until after the socket thread receives its message.

Can anybody tell me a workaround to this problem?

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

```
.... <some coded>

public void onClickLogin(View view) {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "onClickLogin");

    showLoginLoadingPopup();

    String login_id = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_id)).getText().toString();
    String login_pwd = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_pwd)).getText().toString();

    conn = new Connection(handler, 1, null);
    conn.start();
    conn.sendData(Connection.SSPH_USERCERT, new String[] {login_id, login_pwd});
}
```

}

public class Connection extends Thread implements ConnectionConstant {

```
private InetAddress serverAddr;
private int serverPort;
private Socket socket;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
private Handler handler;

public Connection(Handler h, int type, ServerClass server) {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "Conncetion");
    setServerInfo(type, server);
    handler = h;

    try {
        connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.toString(), "Error", e);
    }
}

public void run() {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "run");
    try {
        queue();
        disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(this.toString(), "Information", e);
    }
}

private void connect() throws Exception {
    if (serverAddr != null)
        Log.d(this.toString(), "connect " + serverAddr.getHostName() + "("
                + Integer.toString(serverPort) + ")");
    else
        Log.d(this.toString(), "connect ");
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
    socket.setSoLinger(true, 3000);
    // UTF-8
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            socket.getOutputStream())), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    Log.i(this.toString(), "Socket connected!");
}

private void queue() throws Exception {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "queue");
    while (true) {
        String sRcv = null;
        sRcv = receive();

        if (sRcv.length() > 0)
            parseData(sRcv);

        Thread.sleep(500);
        Thread.yield();
    }
}

private void send(String str) throws IOException {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "send");
    if (!socket.isConnected())
        return;
    Log.i(this.toString(), "Send : " + str);
    out.println(str);
}

private String receive() throws Exception {
    Log.d(this.toString(), "receive");
    if (!socket.isConnected())
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String str = "";

    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.i(this.toString(), "Receive : " + str);
        sb.append(str + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: By the way I am using JAVA for the program and ANDROID for UI

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong, like calling **run** instead of **start** at the thread. Show your code.

Comment: It's hard to say anything useful without looking at the code. Especially for something like thread errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AsyncTask:

```
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // show dialog
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // connect to the server
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // close dialog
        }
    };

    task.execute();
```

`onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()` are invoked on UI thread.

`doInBackground()` is invoked on background thread.

More about AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading",true);
 Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
           //DO ALL NETWORKING
           //FINALLY DO THIS
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
           });     
      };
 Thread T = new Thread(myRun);
 T.start();
```

Comment: I couldn't use this, since my network class is separated with my UI class, but thanks for the info.